# Continuous function rational for every point, Cantor function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure

For Cantor function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), in my sense it is rational on every point. But it is continuous on [0,1], then such a function must be constant. What is the problem?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "rational at every point". The function is _not_ differentiable at every point. It's differentiable almost everywhere, and satisifies $f'=0$ almost everywhere, but that does not imply it's constant.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I mean that f(x) is rational for $x\in [0,1]$.

Comment: It's not rational at every point.

Comment: @DavidMitra I think this may be the problem I'm facing. It is not rational at those end points of intervals removed, right?

Comment: Saying a function is rational _at a point_ makes no sense.

Comment: The image of the Cantor function is NOT a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.